# php function call messes up table

Tags: php

I've got a html table I build from the database:

```
<tr onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_url"]; ?>');">
    <td>
        <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["camera_name"]; ?> 
    </td>
    <td>
      Timezone: <?php echo queryTimezone(); ?> <br> 
      Video Size: <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_size"]; ?> bytes <br>
          Video Length: <?php echo strTime($result_videos[$i]["video_length"]); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form name="myform" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="delete_video" value="Delete" title="Delete this video" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="video_url" value="<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_url"]; ?>" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is this function:

```
function queryTimezone()
{ 
$query = "SELECT timezone FROM #__camcloud_users WHERE user_id=".$user->id;
$db->setQuery($query);
$timezone = $db->loadResult();
return $timezone;
}
```

It messes the table up.  I don't seem to get any php errors and it cuts off the table at the "Timezone:" part and throws it to the top right of the page.  Basically where I call the function `queryTimezone`.  If I change to put this inside the html table it works fine:

```
<tr onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_url"]; ?>');">
    <td>
        <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["camera_name"]; ?> 
    </td>
    <td>
      Timezone: <?php 
$query = "SELECT timezone FROM #__camcloud_users WHERE user_id=".$user->id;
$db->setQuery($query);
$timezone = $db->loadResult();
echo $timezone;
?> <br> 
      Video Size: <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_size"]; ?> bytes <br>
          Video Length: <?php echo strTime($result_videos[$i]["video_length"]); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form name="myform" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="delete_video" value="Delete" title="Delete this video" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="video_url" value="<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_url"]; ?>" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This works fine.  Did I do something wrong with how I call the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function cannot determine what $user->id, therefore doesnt return a valid result... Theres nothing in the function that defines what $user is

Comment: ack, thanks.  I incorrectly assumed because I had `$user =& JFactory::getUser();` and `$db = &JFactory::getDBO();` set globally that it would work...sigh, I've got more to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Use his function declaration instead:

```
function queryTimezone($user,$db)
{ 
   $query = "SELECT timezone FROM #__camcloud_users WHERE user_id=".$user->id;
   $db->setQuery($query);
$timezone = $db->loadResult();
return $timezone;
}
```

call this way:

```
Timezone: <?php echo queryTimezone($user,$db); ?> <br>
```